# setUbiquitous:itemAtURL:destinationURL:error: does not remove the item from iCloud

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, icloud, nsfilemanager

If I send the message

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:NO
                                    itemAtURL:url
                               destinationURL:iCloudURL
                                        error:&err]
```

to remove an item from iCloud, it doesn't actually delete the file on the Ubiquitous Container. Is this the expected behaviour?

The method returns NO and the error object contains

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 512.)"
>
> UserInfo=0x20870970
>   {NSURL=file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/168EE8CD-4CDF-49BE-AD88-1DC7DD9CF25F/Documents/test.txt,
>
> NSUnderlyingError=0x20863a00 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
>   (LibrarianErrorDomain error 2 - Cannot disable syncing on a unsynced
>   item.)"}

Comment: Does it return `YES`? Is `err` populated?

Comment: Just edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. You're trying to delete an item from iCloud that's not in iCloud. When you want to delete an item from iCloud using `setUbiquitous:...`, the item URL (`itemAtURL:`) should be the iCloud URL. The destination URL can be something local (but is ignored if ubiquitous is set to `NO`).

Answer (score 2):

When specifying the "setubiquitous" parameter to "no", your destinationURL needs to be the local url, not the iCloud one. You have your URLs switched

Answer (score 1):

To delete an item on iCloud, you can try this code:

```
NSError *err;
NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
[fileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:_url
                                    options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting
                                      error:&err
                                 byAccessor:^(NSURL* writingURL) {
                                           NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                                           [fileManager removeItemAtURL:writingURL error:nil];
                                 }];
[fileCoordinator autorelease];
```

Good luck!

Comment: `defaultManager` is not thread save. You should use new instance. Also if `err != nil` `byAccessor` block will never be called so you should check this too.

Comment: @Andy This kind of usage has been thread safe for quite a while. ["The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html)